# datetime json dump or load problem during writing and reading file

Tags: python

i have this piece of code in testing currently

```
from_api_response_data = [
  {
    "active": True,
    "available": True,
    "test1": True,
    "test2": "Testing Only",
    "test3": False,
    "test_name": "Tester 1",
    "id": "12345abcxyz",
    "test_url": {
      "url": "/something/others/api/v1/abc123"
    }
  },
  {
    "active": True,
    "available": True,
    "test1": False,
    "test2": "This also a test",
    "test3": False,
    "test_name": "Tester 2",
    "id": "12345abcxyz678",
    "test_url": {
      "url": "/something/others/api/v1/abc1234"
    }
  }
]

filename = 'testingfile.json'
today = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

from_api_response_data.append(
    {
        'last_updated_date': today
    }
)

Path(filename).write_text(
    json.dumps(from_api_response_data, default=vars, indent=2)
)

test_file_json_read = json.loads(
        Path(filename).read_text()
    )

for test in test_file_json_read:
    if test['available']:
        print("true available")
```

what i am trying to simulate is getting data from api and append updated date and write the data into json file. If i remove that part in appending date, my code works fine when finding test['available']

from console output

```
 true available
 true available
```

but with the date append, i will have this error

```
 if test['available']:
  KeyError: 'available'
```

i am not sure why i am not able to read the test['available'] if the date is appended

this is what my testingfile.json showing

```
[
  {
    "active": true,
    "available": true,
    "test1": true,
    "test2": "Testing Only",
    "test3": false,
    "test_name": "Tester 1",
    "id": "12345abcxyz",
    "test_url": {
      "url": "/something/others/api/v1/abc123"
    }
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "available": true,
    "test1": false,
    "test2": "This also a test",
    "test3": false,
    "test_name": "Tester 2",
    "id": "12345abcxyz678",
    "test_url": {
      "url": "/something/others/api/v1/abc1234"
    }
  },
  {
    "last_updated_date": "2022-11-25T09:48:12.765296"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the last dictionary this  `{ "last_updated_date": "2022-11-25T09:48:12.765296" }` doesn't contain the key 'available'. So the exception keyerror will be thrown. To get around it use `get` which return None when the key is not found

```py
for test in test_file_json_read:
    if test.get('available'):
        print("true available")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just doing what you wrote. You have an array for objects in json, and you are trying to get key "available" from each one. When you're adding new object to the array

```
from_api_response_data.append(
    {
        'last_updated_date': today
    }
)
```

you are adding new object with just one key "last_updated_date", so further down the code can't find key "available" in this added object.

You should ether add "last_updated_date" to every object in your array (if it's applicable to each object)

```
for obj in from_api_response_data:
    obj["last_updated_date"] = today
```

or to have json structure to be like

```
{
    "data": [
      ...your objects
    ],
    "last_updated_date": today
}
```